# Wrong x-labels on R histogram of POSIXct timestamp values

Tags: r, histogram

Given four timestamps, one in April, two in May, and one in June, the `hist` function with `month` breaks shows the four labels March, April, May, and July.

```
library(anytime)

dts <- anytime(c(
  "2019-04-15 12:00:00",
  "2019-05-15 12:00:00",
  "2019-05-15 12:00:00",
  "2019-06-15 12:00:00"
))

hist(dts, breaks = "month", format = "%B", freq = TRUE,
     col = c("turquoise", "steelblue"),
     xlab = "month", ylab = "count")
```

[image: histogram image]

This result is at least unexpected.

It turns out that the histogram's breaks were calculated as `2019-03-30 23:00:00 CET,  2019-04-30 00:00:00 CEST, 2019-05-31 00:00:00 CEST, 2019-07-01 00:00:00 CEST` (in the local time zone).

Instead it should have been `2019-04-01 00:00:00 CEST,  2019-05-01 00:00:00 CEST, 2019-06-01 00:00:00 CEST, 2019-07-01 00:00:00 CEST`

Is there a way to get the expected result (labels April, May, June, and July) without calculating the breaks and label texts "by hand"?

Comment: Can you explain why you think that "2019-04-15 12:00:00" should be "2019-04-01 00:00:00 CEST"? What continent are you assuming we should be on?

Comment: Because 2019-04-01 00:00:00 is the lower bound of the bin that contains all April dates.

Comment: Perhaps you can answer this question then: What time zone are you in?

Comment: `Sys.timezone()` is `Europe/Berlin`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I cannot figure out why the graphical output is appearing as indicated above and the questioner doesn't seem to understand my comments that are attempting to clarify the timezone issue, I'll paste in what I'm seeing with his code (in the US Pacific timezone):

[image]

Perhaps this can be the basis for a further discussion of the problem. The code that does this is in `hist.POSIXt` and as I read it, it should be the section that reads:

```
 if (valid == 6L) {
                start$mday <- 1L
                end <- as.POSIXlt(max(x, na.rm = TRUE))
                end <- as.POSIXlt(end + (31 * 86400))
                end$mday <- 1L
                end$isdst <- -1L
                breaks <- seq(start, end, "months")
                ind <- seq_along(breaks[-1L])
                if (right) 
                  breaks[ind] <- breaks[ind] - 86400
                if (missing(format)) 
                  format <- "%Y-%m-%d"
            }
```

So perhaps the call should be modified to set the `right` parameter to FALSE?

```
 png(); hist(dts, breaks = "month", freq = TRUE,
      col = c("turquoise", "steelblue"),
      xlab = "month", ylab = "count", right=FALSE) ; dev.off()
```

[image]

Still cannot understand why you are getting "month-only" formatting. Since `hist` is generic, there's always the possibility that you loaded a package tyhat has a different version. There should have been a warning message about masking.

Comment: The "month-only" formatting comes from the format specification used when creating the image. I have corrected the code sample.

Comment: `right = FALSE` indeed fixes the issue. However, I don't understand why leaving it out gives the observed result.

Comment: I read the code as 1 is being subtracted from the 'breaks' vector when `right`=TRUE.. Not sure what you mean by " leaving it out gives the observed result".

Comment: I meant leaving out the `right = FALSE` parameter. However, I do not understand, why 1 is subtracted from the `breaks` vector. The `right` parameter should probably not affect the value of the breaks at all, but should rather determine which operator (<, >, <=, >=) is to be used when comparing values with the upper and lower bounds of the binning intervals.